# std vector iterator doesn't support address arithmetics?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, std

I am implementing mergeSort, and I need to pass a subvector of the main vector to a fucntion.
I initialize the subvector using iterators from the main vector but it is not initialized.
Please see `b` and `c` vector.

**b** should be [5,1] and **c** should be [7].

What am I doing wrong? what does "symbol is ambiguous" mean? why is it ambiguous?

[image]

Comment: The 'symbol is ambiguous' errors are a symptom that the debugger cannot handle operator overloading very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second iterator should point to one element after the last one.

```
vector<unsigned int> b(v.begin(), v.begin()+middle);
vector<unsigned int> c(v.begin()+middle, v.end());
```

If you want the first part to be bigger, round `middle` upwards instead of towards zero:

```
unsigned int middle = (v.size()+1)/2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Vector v has 3 elements. So v.size() / 2 will be equal to 1. To define vectors b and c you need to write

```
std::vector<unsigned int> b( v.begin(), std::next( v.begin(), middle ) );
std::vector<unsigned int> c( std::next( v.begin(), middle ), v.end() );
```

Take into account that the valid ranges for the vectors are

```
[v.begin(), std::next( v.begin(), middle ) )
```

and

```
[std::next( v.begin(), middle ), v.end() )
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterator ranges are *half-open*. The begin iterator refers the the first element in the range, the end iterator refers to **one past** the last item in the range. This is usually written as `[first, one past last)`.

Putting that together with your code, the range `[v.begin() + middle + 1, v.end()-1)` means "the range starting at middle + 1 and ending last-1" i.e. you're ignoring both the first and last element of the range you wanted.

To solve it, you need to just remove the iterator arithmetic in the second line.